# Solr Grouping Options

Tags: jquery, solr

I am using solr 4.10.3. In solr query I want to use group.offset=5 and group.main=true in same request. I am unable to use them together. They are working with other options but not when combined. Is there any other way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

if you use group.main=true to the request, then it returns back a much more familiar looking response (i.e. it looks like a normal non-grouped response)

so you need to use "start" and "rows" instead of "group.offset". Also do not forget to use "group.limit"